# Split string in a foreach-object loop

Tags: azure, powershell, split, disk

I'm preparing a report for disks in Azure and I want to include a VM name onto which disk is assigned. I found a property called managedby in get-azurermdisk cmdlet, but it represent a whole directory, not the VM name only (which is included at the very end). I want to split a whole string by '/' and want to leave only the very last part of property.

This is the script i prepared:

```
$DISK = Get-AzureRmDisk

$Output = $DISK | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
"Name" = $_.Name
"Resource Group Name" =$_.ResourceGroupName
"Disk Tier" = $_.Sku.Tier
"Disk Type" = $_.Sku.Name
"Managed By" = $_.ManagedBy
"Time Created" = $_.TimeCreated
"Disk Size (in GB)" = $_.DiskSizeGB
"I/O per second" = $_.DiskIOPSReadWrite
"MBps per second" = $_.DiskMBpsReadWrite
"Location" = $_.Location
}
}
```

I already tried to do split:

```
"Managed By" = ($_.ManagedBy).Split('/')[8]
```

And separate loops to fill the "Managed By" column:

```
foreach($dsk in $dsks){
    $vm = $DISK | Where-Object -Property id -EQ $dsk.Name
    $prv = $dsk.ManagedBy.Split('/')[6]
    $managed.Add($vm.Name,$prv)
}

foreach($vm in $Output)
{
    if($ips.ContainsKey($vm."Name"))
    {
        $vm."Managed By"=$ips[$vm."Managed By"]
    }
}
```

Error:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

How can I add a some kind of *ignore when value is null* statement?

Comment: You can add the if function to check if it's null or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the `ManagedBy` is null when you try to split on it.

Just add `if else` for `ManagedBy` in this code block `$Output = $DISK | ForEach-Object{}`,

like below:

```
$Output = $DISK | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
"Name" = $_.Name
"Resource Group Name" =$_.ResourceGroupName
"Disk Tier" = $_.Sku.Tier
"Disk Type" = $_.Sku.Name
"Managed By" = if($_.ManagedBy){$_.ManagedBy.Remove(0,$_.ManagedBy.LastIndexOf('/')+1)}else{"none"}
"Time Created" = $_.TimeCreated
"Disk Size (in GB)" = $_.DiskSizeGB
"I/O per second" = $_.DiskIOPSReadWrite
"MBps per second" = $_.DiskMBpsReadWrite
"Location" = $_.Location
}
}
```

I write a sample code and test result as blow, you can just make some changes to meet your need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally how I deal with this is by using the .net `IsNullOrEmpty` method. You could do this a number of ways, but if you ever want to set a different value in the `else` block, this would make the most sense. Also, you can set the variable to the `if` statement. Powershell evaluates the statement and passes the output to your property.

```
$test = '1,2,3,4'

[PSCustomObject]@{
  name = 'test is a string'
  test = if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($test)){ $test.split(',') }
}

$test = $null

[PSCustomObject]@{
  name = 'test is null'
  test = if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($test)){ $test.split(',') }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are we over thinking this? Did i miss something? Is it a typo?

`foreach($dsk in $dsks)`

Where does `$dsks` come from?